# What is NGINX [notice] signal process started error message

Tags: nginx

With regards to nginx error log, what does `2020/10/23 06:51:45 [notice] 361#361: signal process started` mean?

Some more context:

I have some raspberry pi's communicating with my Django application on a digital ocean Ubuntu droplet running nginx as the web server. These raspberry pi's stopped communicating with my server and they are physically very far from me. I can see their last communication with my server was at 2020/10/23 06:51:41 then they stopped (seconds before nginx error message was logged).
A user that has access to the pi's said they did not lose power, internet is working, so they did a reboot, still nothing.

I have tried:
`sudo systemctl restart nginx` followed by `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`

This did not resolve the issue. I can't seem to find the documentation on this error

Answer (score 1):

That just tells you the process ID nginx started.

As it is at the **[notice]** level, it is just an info msg.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the security group of your instance from digital ocean ? I think your port is not opened for http and HTTPS. Cross check for port 80 and 443. Is it opened or closed.